# jQuery sequence and function call problem

Tags: jquery, load, validation, fullcalendar, ajaxform

I'm very new to jquery and programming in general but I'm still trying to achieve something here.

I use Fullcalendar to allow the users of my web application to insert an event in the database. The click on a day, view changes to agendaDay, then on a time of the day, and a dialog popup opens with a form. I am trying to combine validate (pre-jquery.1.4), jquery.form to post the form without page refresh

The script calendar.php, included in several pages, defines the fullcalendar object and displays it in a div:


    `$(document).ready(function() {`

```
    function EventLoad() {
        $("#addEvent").validate({
            rules: {
                calendar_title: "required",
                calendar_url: {
                    required: false,
                    maxlength: 100,
                    url: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                calendar_title: "Title required",
                calendar_url: "Invalid URL format"
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#addEvent').submit(function() { 
                    var options = { 
                        success:    function() {
                            $('#eventDialog').dialog('close');
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                        } 
                    }; 

                    // submit the form 
                    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
                    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
                    return false; 
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        theme: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: false,
        events: "json-events.php?list=1&<?php echo $events_list; ?>",
        <?php if($_GET['page'] == 'home')
                echo "defaultView: 'agendaWeek',"; 
        ?>
        eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.url) {
                window.open(event.url);
                return false;
            }
        },
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            if (view.name == 'month') {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaDay').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
            }else{
                if(allDay)
                {
                    var timeStamp = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'dddd+dd+MMMM_u');
                    var $eventDialog = $('<div/>').load("json-events.php?<?php echo $events_list; ?>&new=1&all_day=1&timestamp=" + timeStamp, null, EventLoad).dialog({autoOpen:false,draggable: false, width: 675, modal:true, position:['center',202], resizable: false, title:'Add an Event'});
                    $eventDialog.dialog('open').attr('id','eventDialog');
                }
                else
                {
                    var timeStamp = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'dddd+dd+MMMM_u');
                    var $eventDialog = $('<div/>').load("json-events.php?<?php echo $events_list; ?>&new=1&all_day=0&timestamp=" + timeStamp, null, EventLoad).dialog({autoOpen:false,draggable: false, width: 675, modal:true, position:['center',202], resizable: false, title:'Add an Event'});
                    $eventDialog.dialog('open').attr('id','eventDialog');;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The script json-events.php contains the form and also the code to process the data from the submitted form.

What happens when I test the whole thing:
- **first** user click on a day, then time of day. Popup opens with time and date indicated on the form. When user submits the form, dialog closes and calendar refreshes its events.... and the event added by the user appears several times (from 4 to up to 11 times!). The form has been processed several times by the receiving php script?!
- **second** user click, the popup opens, user submit empty form. Form is submitted (validate function not triggered) and user redirected to empty page json-events.php (ajaxForm not triggered either)

Obviously, my code is wrong (and dirty as well, sorry). Why is the submitted form, submitted several time to receiving script and why is the javascript function EventLoad triggered only once ?

Thank you very much for you help. This problem is killing me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I believe I am onto something, this [link](http://www.meppum.com/2009/may/15/using-jquery-validation-ajax-submitted-jquery-ui-d/) brought new lights to my problem. Below is the code that works fine with my application. It's probably a bit dirty, but so far, my tests gave me good results.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Calendar for all pages except for HOME
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            theme: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            editable: false,
            events: "json-events.php?list=1&<?php echo $events_list; ?>",
            <?php if($_GET['page'] == 'home')
                    echo "defaultView: 'agendaWeek',"; 
            ?>
            eventClick: function(event) {
                if (event.url) {
                    window.open(event.url);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                if (view.name == 'month') {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaDay').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
                }else{
                    if(allDay)
                    {
                        var timeStamp = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'dddd+dd+MMMM_u');
                        var $eventDialog = $('<div/>').load("json-events.php?<?php echo $events_list; ?>&new=1&all_day=1&timestamp=" + timeStamp, null, validForm).dialog({
                        autoOpen:false,
                        draggable: false, 
                        width: 675, 
                        modal:true, 
                        position:['center',202], 
                        resizable: false, 
                        title:'Add an Event',
                        buttons: {
                            'Add an Event': function() {
                                    var options = { 
                                        success: function() {
                                            $('#eventDialog').dialog().empty().remove();
                                            $("#addEvent").empty().remove();
                                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                        } 
                                    }; 
                                    // Manually trigger validation
                                    if ($("#addEvent").validate().form() == true) {
                                        $('#addEvent').ajaxSubmit(options);
                                        $('#eventDialog').dialog('close');
                                    }
                            },
                            Cancel: function() {
                                $("#addEvent").empty().remove();
                                $(this).dialog().empty().remove();
                            }
                        }
                        });

                        //$eventDialog.dialog('open').attr('id','eventDialog');
                        $eventDialog.dialog('open', {
                            open: function(event, ui) { $validForm; }
                        }).attr('id','eventDialog');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var timeStamp = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'dddd+dd+MMMM_u');
                        var $eventDialog = $('<div/>').load("json-events.php?<?php echo $events_list; ?>&new=1&all_day=0&timestamp=" + timeStamp, null, validForm).dialog({
                        autoOpen:false,
                        draggable: false,
                        width: 675,
                        modal:true,
                        position:['center',202],
                        resizable: false,
                        title:'Add an Event',
                        buttons: {
                            'Add an Event': function() {
                                    var options = { 
                                        success: function() {
                                            $('#eventDialog').dialog().empty().remove();
                                            $("#addEvent").empty().remove();
                                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                                        } 
                                    }; 
                                    // Manually trigger validation
                                    if ($("#addEvent").validate().form() == true) {
                                        $('#addEvent').ajaxSubmit(options);
                                        $('#eventDialog').dialog('close');
                                    }
                            },
                            Cancel: function() {
                                $("#addEvent").empty().remove();
                                $(this).dialog().empty().remove();
                            }
                        }
                        });

                        //$eventDialog.dialog('open').attr('id','eventDialog');
                        $eventDialog.dialog('open', {
                            open: function(event, ui) { $validForm; }
                        }).attr('id','eventDialog');
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        function validForm(){
            $("#addEvent").validate({
                rules: {
                    calendar_title: "required",
                    calendar_url: {
                        required: false,
                        maxlength: 100,
                        url: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    calendar_title: "Title required",
                    calendar_url: "Invalid URL format"
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks again for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply applying the submit handler when the validation is successful.  You should use the [validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) plugin's submitHandler option to do the actual submission.

```
submitHandler: function() {
        var options = { 
            success:    function() {
                $('#eventDialog').dialog('close');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
            } 
        }; 

        // submit the form 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I applied this modification in the code. The form is no longer submitted to the receiving script.

The other problem, when opening the popup a second time "validate" and "ajaxSubmit" are not triggered, is still there.

P.S. I'm still using jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: Hmmm.  It might have something to do with the EventLoad function being called before you create the dialog.  Have you tried running it in the dialog open event handler?  The dialog might remove the original elements (and their handlers) in 1.3.

Comment: :( Have tried calling the EventLoad function in the dialog open event handler with no luck. Have tried placing the EventLoad function inside the load method with no luck either. I have to admit that I don't exactly understand how the whole sequence is working there.

Comment: Are you using the validation plugin from bassistance.de?  Can you show the updated code with EventLoad in the open handler.  Also, have you tried doing a destroy on the dialog when it's submitted.  Since you're recreating it you probably need to delete the existing one.  Esp. since you give it an id.